# Click event not firing using ON?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i click on any button , `click` event is not fired . Tough i made it work using `$("div").on("click", "button", function () {` but i want to see it working using `.class` selector .

**Syntax of ON:**

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )

**Html:**

```
<div>
    <button class='alert'>Alert!</button>
</div>
```

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div button").on("click", ".alert", function () {
        console.log("A button with the alert class was clicked!");
    });
    $("<button class='alert'>Alert!</button>").appendTo("div");
});
```

sample to work **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26605/)**

It may be basic but i'm seriously starting to try & understand few concepts . Help me understand .

Comment: The selector you're using is incorrect. Use `$('div').on('click', '.alert', function...`. Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26606/)

Comment: @Tushar nice one tough click fires for all elements having class associated .

Comment: Down voter dare to comment

Comment: That's what `event delegation` is. Binding event for dynamically added elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code is trying to delegate the event for element with class alert in button. which do not exists.

If you are trying to delegate the event for button with class alert,You need to use:

```
$("div").on("click", "button.alert", function () {
    console.log("A button with the alert class was clicked!");
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cs1a690m/)**

Comment: Your demo is slightly wrong. The appendTo bit needs to be directly after the console.log, so as to only add the second button after the first has been clicked. See @Rejith R Krishnan's answer.

Comment: @PhillHealey: LOL....that is how it is. the middle part is just comments added by OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div").on("click", "button.alert", function () {
        console.log("A button with the alert class was clicked!");
    });
    $("<button class='alert'>Alert!</button>").appendTo("div");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div button.alert").on("click", function () {
        console.log("A button with the alert class was clicked!");
    });

    $("<button class='alert'>Alert!</button>").appendTo("div");
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26607/) for reference